# Application view in Glade differs from actual application

Tags: quickly, glade

I used Quickly and Glade to create an application for ubuntu.

```
quickly create ubuntu-application SecureLogin
```

Via the Glade Hierarchy section, I removed all the menus except for 'help>contents & about'. It looks like this (in Glade):

http://i442.photobucket.com/albums/qq142/nanieke/3c4663ed.png

But when I run the program (via

```
quickly run
```

or after installing the package), suddenly two other options appear in the menu:

http://i442.photobucket.com/albums/qq142/nanieke/15914525.png

I can't find the content anywhere and don't know where it is created. The options are not shown in the menu 'hierarchy' section in Glade. I searched my project folder for terms like 'Online' and 'Translate', but got no results.

Does anyone have an idea where the options come from and how I can delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two menu entries added *in code* (not through Glade) that are part of the [Launchpad Integration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation/Coding#Launchpad_integration_library) library. You'll find them in `<yourproject>_lib/Window.py`

```
# Optional Launchpad integration
# This shouldn't crash if not found as it is simply used for bug reporting.
# See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Internationalisation/Coding
# for more information about Launchpad integration.
try:
    from gi.repository import LaunchpadIntegration # pylint: disable=E0611
    LaunchpadIntegration.add_items(self.ui.helpMenu, 1, True, True)
    LaunchpadIntegration.set_sourcepackagename('foo')
except ImportError:
    pass
```